# My embed table view controller's cells aren't showing up

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uikit

My embed table view controller's cells aren't showing up. Here is my container view and the connect table view controller. My cells were showing correctly for long time but something happened and they stopped :). Thanks

[image]
[image]

Comment: please share demo project

Comment: here is the link : https://github.com/m4thus4n/project

Comment: which screen is ot showing cell ?

Comment: the one with the container view (title : new item)

Comment: sent you pull request after solving your issue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove these two functions from your controller will solve your issue

```
  override func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        // #warning Incomplete implementation, return the number of sections
        return 0
    }

    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        // #warning Incomplete implementation, return the number of rows
        return 0
    }
```